# Which spring-boot-starter-security supports @EnableWebSecurity and @Preauthorize annotation?

Tags: websecurity, spring-boot-security, spring-boot-starter-security

I need version of spring-boot-starter-security supports @EnableWebSecurity and @Preauthorize annotation?